# Make signup div to pop up when people come to site in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i hava this code

```
 <!-- signup work start here -->
       <div class="signup">
          <div class="signfree">
             <div class="signfree1">
                <h6>Sign up for our FREE <br /><span>bark bulletin!</span></h6>
                <h5>monthly newsletter</h5>
             </div>
             <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/dog_news.png" alt="" />
             <form id="footer">
                <input type="text" value="name" class="name" />
                <input type="text" value="email" class="email" />
                <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit" />
             </form>
          </div>
       </div>
       <!-- signup work end here -->
```

i have this form  to  popup when some user come to my site !!

Answer (score 1):

Try to *hide your div by css* and *show using jquery* the way suggested below.

in css:

```
.signup{ 
    display:none; /* this hides your div when page loads*/ 
}
```

and jQuery:

```
jQuery(function(){  // dom ready function
    jQuery('.signup').show(); // when dom is ready show the element
});
```

Comment: where to put this code do i need jquery.js also before putting the code ??

Comment: as you mentioned that its is `wordpress` so it uses jQuery, so you don't need to add a jQuery library and also you can put this code in the head section of your document.